# MongoDB C# Driver - lookup (aggregation) with an Array not joining

Tags: c#, mongodb, mongodb-query, mongodb.driver

I'm trying to join two collections by the Id utilizing the Lookup(aggregation). Two classes:

```
public class Accountant
{
    [BsonId]
    [BsonRepresentation(BsonType.ObjectId)]
    public ObjectId Id { get; set; }

    [BsonElement("bestClientsIds")]
    [BsonRepresentation(BsonType.ObjectId)]
    public string[] BestClientsIds { get; set; }

    public List<Client> MyClients { get; set; }
}
public class Client
{
    [BsonId]
    [BsonRepresentation(BsonType.ObjectId)] 
    public ObjectId Id { get; set; }

    [BsonElement("clientName")]
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

The query:

```
IMongoCollection<Accountant> collection = mongoDatabase.GetCollection<Accountant>("accountants");
IMongoCollection<Client> foreignCollection = mongoDatabase.GetCollection<Client>("clients");

                var results = collection.Aggregate()
                    .Lookup<Accountant, Client, Accountant>(
                        foreignCollection: foreignCollection,
                        localField: ac => ac.BestClientsIds,
                        foreignField: c => c.Id,
                        @as: ac => ac.MyClients
                    ).ToList().AsQueryable();
```

Documents:

```
accountants:
_id:ObjectId("5deea64bfb49b60019a4ac97")
active:true
bestClientsIds:Array
    0:"5de95d449f4b820413c89e11"
    1:"5d2c1cfb8f4b810011c89e14"
    2:"5d3c1e5a5f4b81e045c89e52"
__v:11


clients:
_id:ObjectId("5d3c1e5a5f4b81e045c89e52")
active:true
clientName:"John Doe"
__v:6

_id:ObjectId("5de95d449f4b820413c89e11")
active:true
clientName:"Mike Davis"
__v:6
```

I can't figure out why this is not working. The join doesn't happen since *ac.MyClients* has no elements even though *ac.BestClientsIds* array does. From what I understand $lookup with an Array is supported. I would really appreciate some assistance. Thx.
(MongoDB v4.2.3, .Net Driver v2.10.1, data types can not be modified).

Comment: Can you show database documents you're trying to join?

Comment: The documents have been added.

Comment: So it looks like `bestClientsIds` contains an array of strings so the `$lookup` will not work as `_id` stores ObjectIds

Comment: From what I was able to find out on line by adding this [BsonRepresentation(BsonType.ObjectId)] it should work so that array represents the proper objects.

Comment: I think `[BsonRepresentation(BsonType.ObjectId)]` should work when you insert new documents but if you have existing data being `string` then you have to covert it first to `ObjectId` - otherwise no data will be returned since there's a type mismatch

Comment: I've made all those fields of type ObjectId and the join is working now.